# C1047 The object or library file '' was created by a different version of the compiler in same solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am getting this error in release mode VS2019.

The below error reported in B project.

> C1047: The object or library file 'A.Lib' was created by
> a different version of the compiler than other objects like 'B.obj'; rebuild all objects and libraries with the same compiler.

I migrated project from VS2015 to vs2019.

Both A and B in same solution.

A.lib generated with VS142 and generate library file as desired.

While build B project in VS142 , it reported this error.

Is any solution for it?

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilt the library?

Comment: The compiler version (tool-chain) is set for each build configuration of the project. So for a project with debug/release and x86/x64 builds you need to check or change the compiler version in 4 places.

Comment: Where we need to change the compiler version?

I am getting this error in Release x64.

Comment: I tried clean and rebuilt both A and B project. getting same error

Comment: Is any suggestion to resolve this issue?

Comment: @RichardCritten
Is anyother way to fix this issue?